Plot ETH 20 EMA on RTH chart on Trading View
I would like to plot a 20 EMA based on ETH data on an RTH chart on trading view.
My script is currently as follows:
// Input for EMA length
emaLength = input(20, title="EMA Length")
// Get the extended hours close prices
extendedTicker = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker, session.extended)
extendedHoursClose = request.security(extendedTicker, timeframe.period, close, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on )
// Calculate the EMA based on extended hours data
extendedEma = ta.ema(extendedHoursClose, emaLength)
plot(extendedEma, color=color.red, title="Extended Hours EMA")

However this is not doing what it should and plots the regular RTH EMA on an RTH chart.

Instead of getting the close price and using it in calculations, you should directly pass the ema() to the security().
extendedEma_2 = request.security(extendedTicker, timeframe.period, ta.ema(close, emaLength), lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(extendedEma_2, color=color.white, title="Extended Hours EMA")

Below are two charts.
Top one is RTH with EMA20 as yellow line. Your original ouput as red line (same as the yellow line) and the white line is what you get when you pass ema() directly to security().
Below chart is ETH with EMA20.


This works. Thanks a lot!
